# How to use a local gitlab-runner to test two jobs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have installed a local gitlab runner to test the `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration. The pipeline I want to test consists of two jobs

```
job1 -> job2
```

`job2` uses data that `job1` generates. `job1` runs for about 10 minutes.

How can I use this local gitlab runner to just test `job2` with the output from `job1`, without running `job1` each time and to wait for its output?

Can I somehow "save" the "state/image" of the gitlab-runner after I have run `job1` once?

Comment: https://github.com/firecow/gitlab-ci-local is a tool i am using locally for testing, i can easily set environment variables to tinder it to my usecase, and i can call jobs on their own - i think this is worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the combination of `artifacts` with `dependencies`.

For example, let's say that your `job1` has an output under the `target` directory, then you could define it like:

```
job1:
  stage: build
  script: ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/
```

and use it in `job2` as:

```
job2:
  stage: test
  script: ...
  dependencies:
    - job1
```

Also, in case that you'd like to refer to artifacts from a Job from a totally different project or even to download them manually, you can always download them using the REST API.

The following URI would download the latest artifacts generated from a successfull job execution:

```
https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=job1
```

You can find more information about `artifacts` and `dependencies` on the official documentation:

- [Job Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html)
- [Artifacts and Dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts)